# Vuforia sdk 10.15 Ground plane not support in samsung s23 even its in supported device list

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, augmented-reality, vuforia

vuforia sdk with unity 3d Ground plane not working in samsung s23 android phone.vuforia and ARcore device support list contain samsung s23 as recommended device but its not working.

we have checked last 3 update of vufoia sdk and samples but at time of initialize its says "Device does not support anchors and hit test functionality."

we are using latest sdk 10.15.4

Comment: Are Google Services for AR installed on the device https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.ar.core&pli=1? Is the PLATFORM_PREFERRED fusion provider selected (https://library.vuforia.com/sites/default/files/references/unity/namespaceVuforia.html#a247a4d24f56f9b41c42bbf8c78c8a554 )?

Answer (score 0):

I updated Unity to the latest stable release which at the current time is 2022.3.8f1 and this solved the issue in my case.

I did this after checking the Vuforia [Documentation](https://library.vuforia.com/platform-support/supported-versions) which provides a suggested version.

Comment: Your last answer was deleted because it wasn't an answer - it just said "I'm having this problem too". Those aren't considered useful contributions here. This answer looks to contain a potential solution though so is fine.